# installing on httpdocs in ubuntu

Tags: drupal

I insatlled drupal on a domain using easy host controll panel. everything went well but when i go to my domain www.webme.com .it comes up with "This site is hosted on an EHCP server, www.ehcp.net, ehcp is a hosting control panel for ubuntu, 
To change this, Upload your files inside httpdocs folder using ftp (such as a program-filezilla or webftp)
The control panel for this server is probably here (http://192.168.0.40/ehcp) (ip:192.168.0.40)
Your local ip: 192.168.0.200"
 i have already created a folder in the httpdocs with all the installation. what particular file should i move to the "httpdocs that will bringup my website when i search "www.webme.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all of your files in root. `httpdocs` is root folder then configure your database conection in `setting.php`.

This is all your job must to do.

Comment: Thanks that works. Please how do I resolve this error "All necessary changes to sites/ default and
sites/ default/ settings.php have been made, so you should remove write pErmissions to them now in order to avoid security risks. If you are unsure how to do so, consult the "

Comment: Hi again, u must put "setting.php" and "default" folder permission to 555
u could read this articel
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/installing-drupal-7/step-3-create-settingsphp-and-the-files-directory